# php submit one of clicked <li>

Tags: php

To display data I have to use onClick on the li tag otherwise I could pass data,
I need to submit clicked item from list, noted that this list is created by loop that mean this name is an array.

How can I submit(post) the value of a clicked (li:input)? I mean the current list index which I clicked?

```
<ul>
    <?php
        for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){?>
            <li>.....value....</li>
            <input type="hidden" name="hide[]" value="..value.."/>                  
     <?php }?>
</ul>
```

I tried before foreach but I cant get my proper own value that I need.

Comment: use jquery aJax to submit as post

Comment: This won't work. The array notation is nothing that helps here. You need to apply a unique value to each hidden input field which you can do in the iteration of the generating loop. Then you need some client side logic to collect the corresponding hidden value and send it.

Comment: Use JQuery and write the "li" as 
                   <li id="<?=$i.'|'.$value;?> onClick="getID(this.id);">...</li>

Thus you will be able to pass the value of $i as well as the content for that $i and do the calculation in your function.

Answer (score 0):

This is only an example of onclick. You have to modify it as per your requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#class").click(function(){
            var name = $(this).val(); 
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"name":name},
                url:"page_name.php",
                success:function(data){
                    $(".success").html(data);//Here you can show success data
                }
            });
        });
    });
```